# Legrand Orange book with cleveref

Tags: templates, cleveref

I'm using the Legrand Orange book template from the [LaTeX Templates website](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/legrand-orange-book) and trying to incorporate `cleveref` package.

It already works well when referencing to sectioning, Tables, Figures etc but puts question marks for theorem-like environments. Currently, I am putting

```latex
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
```

just after `\input{structure.tex}` in `main.tex`. Do I put it in the wrong place or do I get the `\crefname` line wrong?

I use all files unaltered except for `main.tex` of which this is my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations

\input{structure.tex} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template

\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}

%\hypersetup{pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}} % Uncomment and fill out to include PDF metadata for the author and title of the book

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\chapterimage{chapter_head_2.pdf} % Chapter heading image

\chapter{In-text Elements}

\section{Theorems}\index{Theorems}
\label{sec-test}
This is an example of theorems.

\subsection{Single Line}\index{Theorems!Single Line}
This is a theorem consisting of just one line.

\begin{theorem}
A set $\mathcal{D}(G)$ in dense in $L^2(G)$, $|\cdot|_0$. \label{thm-test}
\end{theorem}
\cref{sec-test}\cref{thm-test}
%------------------------------------------------

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Treatments} & \textbf{Response 1} & \textbf{Response 2}\\
\midrule
Treatment 1 & 0.0003262 & 0.562 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table caption}
\label{tab:example} % Unique label used for referencing the table in-text
%\addcontentsline{toc}{table}{Table \ref{tab:example}} % Uncomment to add the table to the table of contents
\end{table}

Referencing \cref{tab:example} in-text automatically.

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{placeholder.jpg}
\caption{Figure caption}
\label{fig:placeholder} % Unique label used for referencing the figure in-text
%\addcontentsline{toc}{figure}{Figure \ref{fig:placeholder}} % Uncomment to add the figure to the table of contents
\end{figure}

Referencing \cref{fig:placeholder} in-text automatically.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the issue exist in other document classes?

Comment: @TeXminator, did you ever get a solution to this?